# Global variable resets when adding a command button with code

Tags: vba, excel

I have this short piece of code

```
Public n As Integer

Public Sub Foo()

    For i = 0 To 4

        MyModule.n = MyModule.n + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

which is defined in a Module named `MyModule`. This code is working as expected: After executing for the first time 'MyModule.n' has the value 5. After executing the second time it has the value 10 and so on.

When I extend the code, to add a CommandButton and place it onto the working sheet, the global variable `MyModule.n` loses it's value on every new call of `Foo`:

```
Public n As Integer

Public Sub Foo()

    Dim btn As OLEObject

    For i = 0 To 4

        Set btn = Worksheets("Aufträge").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
        Left:=122, Top:=321, Width:=30, Height:=30)

        MyModule.n = MyModule.n + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

The code seems to work because the command button is created and placed correctly. Why does the global variable reset if executing the second code fragment?

Furthermore I can't place a break point after or inside the For-Loop in the second code fragment. I get the message `Can't enter break mode at this time`.

Comment: Does the code compile? Do a Debug menu -> Compile and it throws type mismatch. Change the line `MyModule.n = MyModule + 1` to `MyModule.n = MyModule + 1` or `n = n + 1`.

Comment: @shahkalpesh. I think you mean `MyModule.n = MyModule.n + 1` :)

Comment: @shahkalpesh I am sorry - you are right .. but that's only a typo here and not in my source code. I've corrected the code above.

Comment: both code fragments above are compiling and working but in the second the variable n is always starting at its initial value 0 - and that's what makes me crazy :)

Comment: @lastprime - why are you placing 5 buttons on top of each other? What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @Remnant Well that's the issue: If the variable n would count correctly and won't 'forget' its value I would not place those buttons on top of each other :) Well, the code that actually places the buttons is truncated here but the placement doesn't has any effect on the variable n.

Comment: @Remnant What's important is for me here is the question why the variable n is working in the first code fragment but not in the second ...

Comment: @lastprime - This does seem odd. As an alternative you could have a public function that returns `Worksheets("Aufträge").OLEObjects.Count` in order to track the number of buttons (assumes only OLEOBjects on sheet are buttons).

Comment: @Remnant Unfortunately that's not an option for me. Were you able to reproduce the error ? I really don't understand what going on here ... My head hurts and I really have to make progress ...

Comment: @lastprime - yes, i reproduced the error. I think `shahkalpesh` may be correct with his answer below, though hard to verify via code debug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the search I did & my conclusion is that you can't add controls dynamically to the worksheet and retain the state of variables.

Here is why: Adding a button will force the sheet to goto design mode & hence reset of variables.

Supporting links

1. http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/dynamically-adding-activex-controls-via-vba-kills-global-vba-heap-t3763287p2.html
2. https://web.archive.org/web/20101215134333/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231089  (originally //support.microsoft.com/kb/231089)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that this is true. VBA IDE's really should provide more meaningful feedback to the developer .. I spent almost the whole day to try to figure out what is going on here. Nevertheless Thank you very much for your efforts - you did help me a lot ! It's quite good for a VBA programmer (which for god sakes I am not) to know that .. I am wondering how many people have ran into that trap before :) Again, thank you .. you definitely made my day ...

Comment: Based on this information, @lastprime could store the counter in a worksheet cell or a worksheet CustomProperty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a for next loop for the first example. Why don't you do that :

```
Public n As Integer

Public Sub Foo()

    MyModule.n = 5


End Sub
```

This will do the thing in one operation.

In the second example you don't add one button, you add 5 of them. Check the help fo "For Next".

Comment: I just checked your profile and you seem to know programming, I really don't understand your examples then. Why do you use MyModule.n and MyModule ?

Comment: Why are you commenting on your own answer? Did you mean to comment on the question?

Comment: Well as you said the loop is intended. What I want to do is to simply create n buttons which is done inside by the loop. Furthermore I want to keep track of the number of created buttons in a variable which can be accessed by other modules (that's why I defined the variable n outside the procedure). In the first code fragment the global variable seems to 'work' whereas in the second it seems to lose its current value on every call of `Foo`.